# Interacting with a container in Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure-container-instances

Is there a way to execute a command in a container hosted in ACI?  I'm looking for something like this:

```
docker container exec [image] [command]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Azure CLI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest), with a command like:

```
az container exec -g container-group --name container-name --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

For more information, see this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec

However, I've noticed that I currently cannot select the user to run the command as (such as docker exec -u "user").

Answer (score 2):

```
az container exec --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <name of cotainer group> --container-name <name of container app> --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

Source [Execute Commands in Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec)

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but it's on our list. For the moment, the best you can do is SSHing into the container and running your command that way.

Comment: Can you point me to information on how I can do that with an ACI container?  There's no indication in the documentation where/how to connect.  Would I do it through the public IP?